# I have a multiparser to parse the stream when request is MultiPart/ Form-Data. Document Corrupt when Uploading *.docx and *.xlsx files

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I have a multiparser to parse the stream when request is MultiPart/ Form-Data. When Uploading *.docx or *.xlsx files, when opening it says the document is corrupt, but i could able to recover the document , Can you help How i can get rid of this error

Attaching the code snippets.

```
         public class MultipartParser
         {
             public MultipartParser(Stream stream)
             {
                 this.Parse(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
             }
    public static byte[][] Separate(byte[] source, byte[] separator)
            {
                var Parts = new List<byte[]>();
                var Index = 0;
                byte[] Part;
                for (var I = 0; I < source.Length; ++I)
                {
                    if (Equals(source, separator, I))
                    {
                        Part = new byte[I - Index];
                        Array.Copy(source, Index, Part, 0, Part.Length);
                        Parts.Add(Part);
                        Index = I + separator.Length;
                        I += separator.Length - 1;
                    }
                }
                Part = new byte[source.Length - Index];
                Array.Copy(source, Index, Part, 0, Part.Length);
                Parts.Add(Part);
                return Parts.ToArray();
            }

            public static bool Equals(byte[] source, byte[] separator, int index)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < separator.Length; ++i)
                    if (index + i >= source.Length || source[index + i] != separator[i])
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
            private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
            {
                Regex regQuery;
                Match regMatch;
                string propertyType;

                // The first line should contain the delimiter
                byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);
                // Copy to a string for header parsing
                string content = encoding.GetString(data);

                int delimiterEndIndex = content.IndexOf("\r\n");
                if (delimiterEndIndex > -1)
                {
                    string delimiterString = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));
                    byte[] delimiterBytes = encoding.GetBytes(delimiterString);
                    byte[] delimiterWithNewLineBytes = encoding.GetBytes(delimiterString + "\r\n");
                    // the request ends DELIMITER--\r\n
                    byte[] delimiterEndBytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n" + delimiterString + "--\r\n");
                    int lengthDifferenceWithEndBytes = (delimiterString + "--\r\n").Length;

                    byte[][] separatedStream = Separate(data, delimiterWithNewLineBytes);
                    data = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < separatedStream.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // parse out whether this is a parameter or a file
                        // get the first line of the byte[] as a string
                        string thisPieceAsString = encoding.GetString(separatedStream[i]);

                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisPieceAsString)) { continue; }

                        string firstLine = thisPieceAsString.Substring(0, thisPieceAsString.IndexOf("\r\n"));

                        // Check the item to see what it is
                        regQuery = new Regex(@"(?<=name\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                        regMatch = regQuery.Match(firstLine);
                        propertyType = regMatch.Value.Trim();

                        // get the index of the start of the content and the end of the content
                        int indexOfStartOfContent = thisPieceAsString.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") + "\r\n\r\n".Length;

                        // this line compares the name to the name of the html input control, 
                        // this can be smarter by instead looking for the filename property
                        StreamContent myContent = new StreamContent();
                        if (propertyType.ToUpper().Trim() != "FILES")
                        {
                            // this is a parameter!
                            // if this is the last piece, chop off the final delimiter
                            int lengthToRemove = (i == separatedStream.Length - 1) ? lengthDifferenceWithEndBytes : 0;
                            string value = thisPieceAsString.Substring(indexOfStartOfContent, thisPieceAsString.Length - "\r\n".Length - indexOfStartOfContent - lengthToRemove);
                            myContent.StringData = value;
                            myContent.PropertyName = propertyType;
                            if (StreamContents == null)
                                StreamContents = new List<StreamContent>();

                            StreamContents.Add(myContent);
                            this.Success = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // this is a file!
                            regQuery = new Regex(@"(?<=filename\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                            regMatch = regQuery.Match(firstLine);
                            string fileName = regMatch.Value.Trim();

                            // get the content byte[]
                            // if this is the last piece, chop off the final delimiter
                            int lengthToRemove = (i == separatedStream.Length - 1) ? delimiterEndBytes.Length : 0;
                            int contentByteArrayStartIndex = encoding.GetBytes(thisPieceAsString.Substring(0, indexOfStartOfContent)).Length;
                            byte[] fileData = new byte[separatedStream[i].Length - contentByteArrayStartIndex - lengthToRemove];
                            Array.Copy(separatedStream[i], contentByteArrayStartIndex, fileData, 0, separatedStream[i].Length - contentByteArrayStartIndex - lengthToRemove);
                            // save the fileData byte[] as the file
                            myContent.PropertyName = propertyType;
                            myContent.FileName = fileName;
                            myContent.IsFile = true;
                            myContent.Data = fileData;
                            if (StreamContents == null)
                                StreamContents = new List<StreamContent>();
                            StreamContents.Add(myContent);
                            this.Success = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
          private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (read <= 0)
                            return ms.ToArray();
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }
            }

            public List<StreamContent> StreamContents { get; set; }

            public bool Success
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            public string ContentType
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            public string Filename
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            public List<byte[]> FileContents
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }
        }

/**** Class to store the data **********/
    public class StreamContent
        {
            public byte[] Data { get; set; }
            public bool IsFile { get; set; }
            public string FileType { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }
            public string StringData { get; set; }
        }
```

Please Help!!!!!

Thanks in advance.
Nithin Abraham Paul

Comment: You say you get an error. What is the exact error and which line does it get thrown on?

Comment: I am getting it correctly for all kinds of attachments , but the problem is when i open the attachments the files *.docx and xlsx files  is showing error that the document is corrupt but i could recover the doc, but wanted to know how can i get rid of that error. And i am getting this only for *.docx and *.xlsx  extensions.

Comment: try this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/11/30/excel-open-corrupt-files/

Comment: i am getting excatly the same error as mentioned above, how can i get rid of this error programmatically